# Flutter:: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file://image name

Tags: image, dart, flutter

When trying to add images inside gridview.count Widget. Images are not getting loaded and getting flowing error in console.

Images are placed in local - asset Folder

```
body: center(
  child:gridview.count(
  crossaxiscount: 3,
  childaspectratio: 1.0,
  padding: const edgeinsets.all(4.0),
  mainaxisspacing: 4.0,
  crossaxisspacing: 4.0,
  children: <string>[
    'spinach_onion_salad.png',
    'veggie.png',
  ].map<widget>((string url) {
    return gridtile(
      footer: gridtilebar(
        title: text(url)
      ),
      child: image.network(url, fit: boxfit.cover)
    );
  }).tolist(),
   ),
 ),
```

Error:

```
Error:: 
Reloaded 0 of 426 libraries in 937ms.
Reloaded 6 of 426 libraries in 1,338ms.
I/flutter (32327): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (32327): The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:

I/flutter (32327): Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///%20eggie.png
I/flutter (32327):
I/flutter (32327): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (32327): #0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2121:9)
I/flutter (32327): #1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2056:48)\
```

Comment: Are the images local or via network? if they local use Image.assets("")

Comment: Images in local. but not able to add The class 'Image' doesn't have a constructor named 'assets'.

Comment: ok it is Image.asset("") let me check

Comment: yes Image.asset("")

Comment: If they are local images do not forget to add them to pubspec.yaml and use Image.asset method

Answer (score 0):

```
 return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          children: <String>[
            'spinach_onion_salad.png',
            'veggie.png',
          ]
              .map<Widget>((String url) => GridTile(
                  footer: GridTileBar(title: Text(url)),
                  child: Image.asset(url)))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```